# Select One field from hibernate audit history

Tags: java, hibernate, audit

i want to fetch only one feild (PK of entity) from hibernate audit.
below code gives me whole entity not one field

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
List<Contact> contactList = reader.createQuery()
                            .forRevisionsOfEntity(Contact.class, true, true)
                            .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").between(startDate, endDate))
                            .getResultList();
```

I also tried as below but it throws null pointer exception

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
List<Contact> contactList = reader.createQuery()
                            .forRevisionsOfEntity(Contact.class,"ID", true, true)
                            .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").between(startDate, endDate))
                            .getResultList();
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.envers.query.criteria.CriteriaTools.checkPropertyNotARelation(CriteriaTools.java:41)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.criteria.BetweenAuditExpression.addToQuery(BetweenAuditExpression.java:48)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:99)
at org.hibernate.envers.query.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractAuditQuery.java:110)
at com.unifyv4.ejb.service.subscription.SubsService.getupdatedAccountDetail(SubsService.java:4249)
```

Comment: want to fetch Contact.class's field i.e. Contact.ID

Answer (score 0):

You can query for a different subset of data by setting a projection to the query:

```
query.addProjection(AuditEntity.id);
```

When you do that and you call getResultList the result list will contain a list of IDs rather than a list of entities.

Comment: i want to fetch Contact.class's field i.e. Contact.ID